# What does redefining static methods mean in Java?

Tags: java, scjp

I've been reading a section on Statics in the SCJP study guide, and it mentions the following :

> static methods can't be overridden,
>   but they can be redefined

What does redefining actually mean? Is it a case of having a static method that exists in both parent and child, with the same signature, however they are referenced separately by their class names? Such as :

```
class Parent
{
   static void doSomething(String s){};
}

class Child extends Parent
{
   static void doSomething(String s){};
}
```

Referenced as : `Parent.doSomething();` and `Child.doSomething();` ?

Also, does the same apply for static variables, or just static methods?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It simply means that the functions are not virtual. As an example, say that you have an object of (runtime) type Child which is referenced from a variable of type Parent. Then if you invoke `doSomething`, the `doSomething` method of the Parent is invoked:

```
Parent p = new Child();
p.doSomething(); //Invokes Parent.doSomething
```

If the methods were non-static, `doSomething` of Child would override that of Parent and `child.doSomething` would have been invoked.

The same holds for static fields.

Answer (score 6):

Static means there is one per class, rather than one per object. This is true for both methods and variables.

A static field would imply that there is one such field, no matter how many objects of that class are created. Please take a look at [Is there a way to override class variables in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/685300/509840) for the question of overriding a static field. In short: a static field cannot be overridden.

Consider this:

```
public class Parent {
 static int key = 3;

 public void getKey() {
  System.out.println("I am in " + this.getClass() + " and my key is " + key);
 }
}

public class Child extends Parent {

 static int key = 33;

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Parent x = new Parent(); 
  x.getKey();
  Child y = new Child();
  y.getKey();
  Parent z = new Child();
  z.getKey();
 }
}

I am in class tools.Parent and my key is 3
I am in class tools.Child and my key is 3
I am in class tools.Child and my key is 3
```

Key never comes back as 33. However, if you override getKey and add this to Child, then the results will be different.

```
@Override public void getKey() {
 System.out.println("I am in " + this.getClass() + " and my key is " + key);
}
I am in class tools.Parent and my key is 3
I am in class tools.Child and my key is 33
I am in class tools.Child and my key is 33
```

By overriding the getKey method, you are able to access the Child's static key.

Answer (score 0):

In rajah9's answer if now we make the two methods static both in parent and child:

```
public static void getKey() {
        System.out.println("I am in and my key is " + key);
    }
```

Two things to note now:
Can't use 'this.getClass()' and warning 'The static method getKey() from the type Parent should be accessed in a static way' also

```
Parent z = new Child();
  z.getKey();
```

Will give the output

```
I am in class tools.Parent and my key is 3
```

instead of

```
I am in class tools.Parent and my key is 33
```