# Why does Java enforce return type compatibility for overridden static methods?

Tags: java, static, overriding

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223386/why-doesnt-java-allow-overriding-of-static-methods) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609842/what-does-redefining-static-methods-mean-in-java), Java static methods aren't virtual and can't be overridden. Intuitively, therefore, this should work (even if in 99% of cases it's dangerous programming):

```
class Foo
{
    public static String frob() {
        return "Foo";
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    public static Number frob() {
        return 123;
    }
}
```

However, in practice this gets you:

```
Foo.java:10: frob() in Bar cannot override frob() in Foo; attempting to use incompatible return type
found   : java.lang.Number
required: java.lang.String
    public static Number frob() {
                         ^
```

Naively, it seems like `Foo.frob()` and `Bar.frob()` should have nothing to do with one another; yet Java insists that they do. Why?

(N.b.: I don't want to hear why it would be a bad idea to code this way, I want to hear what it is in Java and/or the JVM design that makes this restriction necessary.)

---

**Updated to add:** For those who think the compiler's going to get confused by calling static methods on instances, if you allow this: it won't. It already has to figure this out in the case where the method signatures *are* compatible:

```
class Foo
{
    static String frob() {
        return "Foo";
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    static String frob() {
        return "Bar";
    }
}

class Qux {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo f = new Foo();
        Foo b = new Bar();
        Bar b2 = new Bar();

        System.out.println(f.frob());
        System.out.println(b.frob());
        System.out.println(b2.frob());
    }
}
```

gets you:

```
Foo
Foo
Bar
```

The question is, what's the concrete reason why it couldn't as easily (in the incompatible-signatures case) get you:

```
Foo
Foo
123
```

Answer (score 7):

Consider the following:

```
public class Foo {
  static class A {
    public static void doThing() {
      System.out.println("the thing");
    }
  }

  static class B extends A {

  }

  static class C extends B {
    public static void doThing() {
      System.out.println("other thing");
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    A.doThing();
    B.doThing();
    C.doThing();
  }
}
```

Run it!  It compiles and prints out

```
the thing
the thing
other thing
```

Static methods sort of inherit -- in the sense that `B.doThing` is translated into a call to `A.doThing` -- and can sort of be overridden.

This seems like it was mostly a judgement call for the JLS.  The most specific way the JLS seems to address this, though, is [section 8.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.2), which simply doesn't say that static methods *aren't* inherited.

Comment: I'm not positive this was necessarily the best possible decision -- it did lead to awkwardnesses like [this code in Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSortedSetFauxverideShim.java) -- but it's not an unreasonable decision, and I assume that they had reasons for this judgement call that I haven't thought of yet.

Comment: `myB` will call the the `doThing()` off of `myB`'s type.

Comment: I meant to imply that `myB` was of type `B`, which didn't override `A.doThing()`.  ;)

Comment: @LouisWasserman "Run it! It compiles" which is why here we are trying to say Java should have not allowed this kind of thing to compile, I mean B.doThing(); should have thrown a compiler error if Java was smart.

Comment: Like I said, there's a certain amount of judgement call.  For example, if this was forbidden, then if `A` has static and non-static methods, and `B extends A`, then should you be able to use the static methods of `A` in `B` without qualification? It's a tricky decision, and there are arguments in each direction.

Comment: First of all, you can never override static methods (a base type referring to a sub type and calling a static method on base type will always call the base's static method); second, both these are 'void' methods. Change the return type of one of them, and the compiler complains.

Answer (score 3):

[JLS 8.4.2 Method Signature](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.4.2), briefly:

> Two methods have the same signature if they have the same name and argument types.

Nothing is said about staticness. Static methods can be called through an instance (or a null reference)--how should the method resolve if a subclass is referenced via a superclass declaration?

Comment: The compiler is already capable of resolving this -- see my comment on [Ryan Shillington's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9439532/27358).

Comment: @DavidMoles Then it's simply "because Java doesn't allow methods to have the same signature but different return types." As for the rational, you'd need to ask Gosling/etc. but most of it resolves to "it's an easy way to eliminate a particular type of user error."

Answer (score 2):

It is because in Java, a particular method is called based on the run time type of the object and not on the compile time type of it. However, static methods are class methods and hence access to them is always resolved during compile time only using the compile time type information. That is, what would happen if you could compile the above and use code like this

```
Foo bar = new Bar();
bar.frob();
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. In your example I would expect `Foo.frob()` to be called as `bar` is a `Foo`.

Comment: @SteveKuo But normal Java signature rules come in to play in this case; inherited methods can't have the same params and different return types.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the JVM could probably be made to allow that, but let's talk about why it's a pretty bad idea from a compiler perspective.

The instance data (including which type the instance is) isn't something that is a simple problem to solve at compile time.  Obviously it's well known at runtime.  If I have a variable bar of type Bar, and I call s = bar.frob(), the compiler would need to reverse engineer what type bar is to see if the return value is acceptable.  If determining the type at compile time is a super hard problem, this makes the compiler inefficient at best. At worst the answer is wrong and you get runtime errors that should have been caught at compile time.

Comment: I don't buy this argument. The compiler already has a rule for this. If `b` is declared to be `Bar`, then `b.frob()` is `Bar.frob()`, and if `b` is declared to be `Foo`, then even if `b` is *actually* an instance of `Bar`, `b.frob()` is `Foo.frob()`. This is easy to demonstrate if you create an example where the types are compatible.

Comment: As far as the JVM is concerned, it'll search down the inheritance hierarchy for an exact match including return type. It ignores "covariant return types" and the like.