# Make method return type generic

Tags: java, generics

I have the following Manager Class with the builder() method:

```
public class Manager extends Employee {

    public static Manager.Builder builder() {
        return new ManagerBuilder();
    }

    public abstract static class Builder<T extends Employee, B extends Builder<T,B>> extends Employee.Builder<T,B>{
    }

    public static class ManagerBuilder extends Builder<Manager,ManagerBuilder> {

    @Override
    protected ManagerBuilder self() {
        return this;
    }

        @Override
    public Manager build() {
        return new Manager(this);
    }
    }
}
```

unfortunatelly trying to build an Object with `Manager.builder().age(25).build();` **return a Person and not a Manager as I need**.

How should I change the Manager.builder() return type to return a Manager and at the same time not clashing with the Employee.builder() Method signature.

The code `Employee.builder().age(25).build();` returns Employee, which is fine.

The Employee Class is looking like this:

```
public class Employee extends Person {

    public static Employee.Builder<Employee, EmployeeBuilder> builder() {
        return new EmployeeBuilder();
    }

    public abstract static class Builder<T extends Person, B extends Builder<T,B>> extends Person.Builder<T,B>{

    }

    public static class EmployeeBuilder extends Builder<Employee, EmployeeBuilder> {

    @Override
    protected EmployeeBuilder self() {
        return this;
    }
    @Override
    public Employee build() {
        return new Employee(this);
    }
    }

}

public class Person implements PersonInterface {

    private Optional<Integer> age;

    protected Person(Builder<?,?> builder) {
        this.age = builder.age;
        }

    public abstract static class Builder<T extends Person, B extends Builder<T,B>> {
        private Optional<Integer> age;

        protected Builder() {
        }

        public B age(Integer age) {
            if (Objects.isNull(age) || age == 0)  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Age ist empty");
            this.age = Optional.of(age);
            return self();
        }

        protected abstract B self();
        public abstract T build();
    }

    public static class PersonBuilder extends Builder<Person, PersonBuilder>{

        @Override
        protected PersonBuilder self() {
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public Person build() {
            return new Person(this);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: please also add the `age()` method and the `Builder` class

Comment: I have added the age() and the Person class, thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your code works perfectly, and `Manager.builder().age(25).build()` actually returns a `Manager`. It is only a compile time problem.

The following Junit test should succeed (it does on my tests):

```
@Test
public void testEss3() throws Exception {
    Person emp = Manager.builder().age(25).build();
    assertTrue(emp instanceof Manager);
}
```

In fact, it looks like as you declare no variable to host the builder, and as the method `age` is not defined in `Manager.Builder` nor in its direct subclass `Employee.Builder`, the Java compiler assume that it will return an object of the class in which it is declared, that is a `Person.Builder`. It is not false because it is actually an ancestor class. But from that point, the compiler do not know the exact class returned by `build()` and only knows that it will be a `Person`.

But the following code is accepter by the compiler:

```
    Manager.Builder<Manager,?> builder = Manager.builder();
    Manager emp = builder.age(25).build();
```

Answer (score 2):

The core problem is your strange inheritance structure which overloads the classname `Builder`. I cant' quite pin the problem down, but at some point your specific type information of `ManagerBuilder` is lost. This can be simplyfied a lot:

```
public class Employee extends Person {

    public static EmployeeBuilder builder() {
        return new EmployeeBuilder();
    }

    public static class EmployeeBuilder extends Person.Builder<Employee, EmployeeBuilder> {

        @Override
        protected EmployeeBuilder self() {
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public Employee build() {
            return new Employee(this);
        }
    }
}

public class Manager extends Employee {

    public static ManagerBuilder builder() {
        return new ManagerBuilder();
    }

    public static class ManagerBuilder extends Person.Builder<Manager, ManagerBuilder> {

        @Override
        protected ManagerBuilder self() {
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public Manager build() {
            return new Manager(this);
        }
    }
}
```

This should solve a few of your problems.

Now you are left with one more problem. The static method `builder` is overloaded with incompatible return types. You find information about this at [Why does Java enforce return type compatibility for overridden static methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439379/why-does-java-enforce-return-type-compatibility-for-overridden-static-methods)
If you name those methods differently, it should work.

Comment: this is interesting, however I need ManagerBuilder to extend Employee.EmployeeBuilder and not Person.Builder and then it starts to get ugly.
public static class EmployeeBuilder<T,B> extends Person.Builder<Employee,EmployeeBuilder> do not work