# Java overriding inherited string

Tags: java

I have an Abstract class, which is derived by another Concrete class. In my abstract class I have a property which is called in method of the same Abstract class. This property is empty in Abstract class but in derived I set a value to it. Nevertheless, when compiler launches the method it takes abstract class' variable, not regarding that I'm launching this method on an Object of the derived class. How do I get the actual URL var instead of null ?

```
abstract public class AbstractHTTPFactory {
    protected String URL = null;

    final public ArrayList<? extends LGCookObject> make() throws HTTPFactoryException{
        try {
            String response = sr.getData(URL);
            }
    }
}

public class RecipesHTTPFactory extends AbstractHTTPFactory{
    protected String URL = "VALUE";
}
```

Comment: How are you calling the property?

Comment: Try to change the var value in the constructor

Comment: you may look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/685300/is-there-a-way-to-override-class-variables-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fields aren't polymorphic. If you want polymorphic behaviour, you'll need *methods*:

```
public abstract class AbstractHTTPFactory {
    public final ArrayList<? extends LGCookObject> make()
            throws HTTPFactoryException {
        String response = sr.getData(getURL());
        ...
    }

    protected abstract String getURL();
}

public class RecipesHTTPFactory extends AbstractHTTPFactory {
    protected String getURL() {
        return "VALUE";
    }
}
```

Or potentially you could have a field in `AbstractHTTPFactory` which is supplied to the constructor:

```
public abstract class AbstractHTTPFactory {
    private final String url;

    public final ArrayList<? extends LGCookObject> make()
            throws HTTPFactoryException {
        String response = sr.getData(url);
        ...
    }

    protected AbstractHTTPFactory(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}

public class RecipesHTTPFactory extends AbstractHTTPFactory {
    public RecipesHTTPFactory() {
        super("VALUE");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to keep the URL definition in your abstract base class, set it's value in the derived concrete class instead of redefine a variable with the same name which will hide the base class one. It's not a good practice though since there will be mysterious variables appear in derived class.