# Java Field Hiding

Tags: java, field, instance-variables, static-variables, member-hiding

I was wondering what it means to say a field is hidden between 2  java classes and
what it means when running code in terms of resulting output?

I have an abstract class with a `protected static boolean field = false` and a sub class
which has a boolean field with the same name but is not static and set to `true`.

If I had this code:

```
Superclass d = new subclass();
```

what would be the value of the boolean field in the superclass and the boolean field
in the subclass? Does subclass field stay as `false` after the assignment above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`static` members are never overridden (and certainly not by non-static members). And since you should access them like this: `ClassName.member` there is also no need to worry about hiding them.

In your case, you would access the `Superclass` field like this: `Superclass.field`. And the field of a `Subclass` instance like this: `subclass.field`. If you have, however a `Subclass` instance in a `Superclass` variable like above, this code: `d.field` will access the static field defined in `Superclass`, which will be `false` in your case.

But this does not change the value of the `Subclass` instance, it just accesses the "wrong" member! You can verify this by putting the instance in `d` back into a `Subclass` variable and reading `field` again.

Comment: Thanks rolve this has really helped

Comment: I'd add to this as to WHY that happens, as I had to search to find out as well.  Found the answer here: (http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/what-is-variable-hiding-and-shadowing/15)

"Because variables names in Java are resolved by the reference type, not the object they are referencing."

Answer (score 10):

- #### *Java Language Specification*

  > If the class declares a field with a certain name, then the declaration of that field is said to *hide* any and all accessible declarations of fields with the same name in superclasses, and superinterfaces of the class.
  >
  > A hidden field can be accessed by using a qualified name if  it is `static`, or by using a field access expression that contains the keyword `super` or a cast to a superclass type.

  <sup>See more in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html</sup>
- #### Example Code

  ```
  class A {
      static int field;
  }
  class B extends A {
      int field;
      void doSomething() {
          System.out.println(super.field); // From A
          System.out.println(field); // From B
      }
  }
  class Main {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          B b = new B();
          System.out.println(b.field); // From B
          System.out.println(((A) b).field); // From A
          System.out.println(A.field); // From A
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

> what would be the value of the boolean field in the superclass and the
>   boolean field in the subclass?

The value of `field` variable in superclass will remain false and the value of `field` in the subclass will remain true.

> Does subclass field stay as FALSE after the assignment above?

No. You cannot override static variables in Java. What essentially happens is the definition in the sub class hides the variable declared in the super class.

For a nice example and explanation, see [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685300/is-there-a-way-to-override-class-variables-in-java)

I also suggest you try it out yourself to see what happens.

Comment: Thanks Suresh for the example I will have a go