# What happens when a Static Variable has the same name as a Static Class in Java?

Tags: java

In the java example below, can anyone explain exactly why the output of the program is "Orange" ? (this is an interview question)

```
public class Finder {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(X.Y.Z);
  }
}

class X {
  static W Y = new W();
  static class Y {
    static String Z ="Apple";
  }
}

class W {
  String Z = "Orange";
}
```

Comment: class `W` is not static, nor is class `X`, **but** W was *declared* static which "over-wrote" the *inner* class inside `X` within the class `X` called `Y` which was declared static (look at `new` within the declaration inside class `X` which came before "attempted" declaration of class `Y`!).

Comment: `X.Y` this expression points to the static variable `Y` defined in class `X`. `Y` variable in class `X` is object of type `W`, therefore, `X.Y.Z` must be `orange`. To get `Apple` you must use `new X.Y().Z`

Comment: That's a nasty interview question. Note that `static W Y` violates the Java naming conventions for variables. (So do `static String Z` in class `Y` and `String Z` in class `W`.) @t0mm13b - the order of declarations has nothing to do with this case.

Comment: @TedHopp you've got me there, tbqh, was never asked that question before in an interview but from reading other's answers, it is a bloody nasty question to pose - in fairness, what was the interviewer's point? Picture yourself as an interviewer, knowing the pitfalls of that question - question is, would you pose that to a potential candidate? What does it have a bearing on the real world - you must be joking if that code was found in production?

Comment: Also, I really do think the interviewer was *forgive* me, taking the p!ss, because who the hell would carry a java spec in their head prior to interview...clearly, it was easy for @fgb to google the spec straight away and post an answer which is enlightening - not knocking the answerer, in fairness that sums up one thing I can gather from the interviewer, he/she has lost a lot of potential candidates as a result of taking the p!ss out of someone with a question like that!

Comment: Not even the compiler writers got these rules right: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do;jsessionid=dc3d7ac7e5c89ffffffffea41bef24e421b5?bug_id=6865517. I've never seen code like this, not even in examples of what not to do.

Comment: @fgb - I've never seen it in production code either, and I would not want to work with someone who wrote such garbage. However, I believe that some obfuscation tools use tricks like this. I don't recall seeing it used for a static field and a static nested class, but I have seen obfuscated code where a class and a package have the same name (e.g., a class `b` in package `a` and also a package `a.b`). This sends many (most?) decompilation tools off the tracks. If the job was to work on a decompilation tool or a JVM, then this _might_ be a justifiable interview question; otherwise...no way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The variable Y obscures the type Y. See the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1):

> 6.4.2. Obscuring
>
> A simple name may occur in contexts where it may potentially be
> interpreted as the name of a variable, a type, or a package. In these
> situations, the rules of §6.5 specify that a variable will be chosen
> in preference to a type, and that a type will be chosen in preference
> to a package. Thus, it is may sometimes be impossible to refer to a
> visible type or package declaration via its simple name. We say that
> such a declaration is obscured.

The qualified name X.Y.Z is resolved according to:

> 6.5.2. Reclassification of Contextually Ambiguous Names
>
> ...
>
> If the name to the left of the "." is reclassified as a TypeName, then:
>
> - If the Identifier is the name of a method or field of the type denoted by TypeName, this AmbiguousName is reclassified as an ExpressionName.
> - Otherwise, if the Identifier is the name of a member type of the type denoted by TypeName, this AmbiguousName is reclassified as a TypeName.
> - Otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.

This is unlikely to occur in practice because of the normal naming conventions for types and variables.

Answer (score 3):

You're hiding the class Y with a static instance of W named Y. The class Y is still there and can be used. Try:

```
System.out.println(X.Y.Z);
System.out.println((new X.Y()).Z);
```

The output should be

```
Orange
Apple
```

Also see: [Java Field Hiding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501503/java-field-hiding)

Comment: Aren't You trying to a access the static class Y in a non-static way by creating an object (new X.Y()).Z). Nothing technically wrong though