# Overload Java Data Field Type by Another Field Type

Tags: java

Is it possible to overload a field type to be another field type?

If so, would it be possible to provide some examples?

Comment: why don't you go try it out and see what happens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't *overload* fields (only methods can be overloaded), you might be confused with *overriding* fields - which anyway is not possible, you end up hiding the fields from superclasses. Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685300/is-there-a-way-to-override-class-variables-in-java).

Comment: I thought this was the case and I was bit confused at first when they came to me about it. I have only been programming Java for three years now and have not came across this. Just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything.

Comment: @BrandonWilson it is not possible

Answer (score 0):

I believe that java supports interfaces, and interfaces should be able to help you achieve what you're trying to achieve

[here's an example i found quick](http://www.codemiles.com/java-examples/java-interface-example-t3505.html)

[here's a tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html)

just make sure that you're not overloading public members that way.

Answer (score 0):

look at this code

```
class A<T> {
    protected T field1;
}

class B extends A<String> {
    public char field1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new B();
        a.field1 = 12442;
    }
}
```

it runs without any exception,
if field1 overrided, it should raise an exception, but it doesn't

and also this runs without any exception

```
class A<T> {
    protected T field1;
}

class B extends A<Character> {
    public char field1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new B();
        a.field1 = 12442;
    }
}
```

It's impossible

Answer (score 0):

**The Java language (JLS) does not allow it, but Java bytecode (JVMS) does**

Oracle JDK 1.8.0_45 even relies on it to implement `assert`. For example:

```
public class Assert {
    static final int[] $assertionsDisabled = new int[0];
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(int.length);
        assert System.currentTimeMillis() == 0L;
    }
}
```

generates two `Oracle JDK 1.8.0_45`, one explicit (`int[]`) and one synthetic (`bool`), and is happily able to distinguish between them. But if we had declared:

```
static final boolean $assertionsDisabled = false;
```

it would fail to compile with:

```
the symbol $assertionsDisabled conflicts with a compile synthesized symbo
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31355548/895245 for more details.

**Possible rationale why it's not possible**

The problem is that it would not be possible to determine the type of the field. Consider:

```
void f(int i) { System.out.println("int"); }
void f(float i) { System.out.println("float"); }
int i;
float i;
// Which overridden method is called?
void m() { f(i); }
```