# How can I have two custom UICollectionViewCell classes share the same variable name

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, oop, uicollectionview

I am having two custom `UICollectionViewCell` classes, however, I want to create a variable of them with the same name in the same scope because all properties and all code in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method is same for both custom cells.

I want to do something like this:
ex:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


CustomCell1/CustomCell2 *cell;

if (condition) {
    cell = (CustomCell1 *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCustomCell1Identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
} else {
    cell = (CustomCell2 *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCustomCell2Identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
}

    // Remaining code is same for both custom cells
    cell.property1 = value1;
    cell.property2 = value2;
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    //lot of code
    cell.property100 = value100;

return cell;
}
```

My purpose behind this is that I don't want to repeat all that remaining code. I know that creating common custom cell class and writing this condition in that common class might be the solution but in that how can I pass condition variable to custom class before that class gets initialized. Because I think we can't initialize (alloc init) UICollectionViewCell.

Is this possible with the conditional(ternary) operator?

Comment: Use a base class and add the common methods in it and derive the cells from that class. This will solve your problem.

Comment: Subclass or protocol could work. And when I see `cell.propertyN = valueN` where N is from 0 to 100, I'd suggest to create a method that would do it with a object (NSArray ? NSDictionary) inside the cell.

Comment: @Larme I have given cell.propertyN = valueN just as an example. Actually, there is a lot of code like assigning images, hiding and showing different subviews, changing colours etc.

Comment: I think @ShaileshChandavar comment will help you.

Comment: Why do you have created the same classes that have the same properties? Are these two classes identical? If it's not then please create a parent class that has common ivar and methods then create child classes inheriting the parent class

Comment: Is using the base class only solution? Isn't there any way to write variables having same name but different type in one scope like mentioned http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13657026/variables-having-same-name-but-different-type here.

Comment: @InderKumarRathore I have created two classes because their layout is different depending on one condition but all subviews and their values are same. I am handling their layout programmatically using Purelayout,and I have written that layout separately for each cell in their implementations.

Comment: @ViruMax you can use same class for two xibs

Comment: @InderKumarRathore Actually layout was created programmatically, so Shailesh's solution worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a base(parent) collectionviewCell class

```
@interface BaseCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell 
//Add the common methods(can add common IBOulet and IBAction) and implement them.
@end
```

Now you can create new collection view cell which is derived from BaseCollectionViewCell as:

```
@interface ChildCell : BaseCollectionViewCell
//add methods which are specific to the ChildCell as the methods of    
//BaseCollectionViewCell is already available via inheritance.
@end
```

same way you can created another collection view cell as:

```
@interface ChildCell2 : BaseCollectionViewCell
//add methods which are specific to the ChildCell2 as the methods of    
//BaseCollectionViewCell is already available via inheritance.
@end
```

Now ChildCell and ChildCell2 gets all the methods of BaseCollectionViewCell.

Register your collection view cells to these classes along with separate reuse identifier.
Use following code to dequeue the cell.

```
 BaseCollectionViewCell *cell;

  if (condition) {

  ChildCell *cell1 = (ChildCell *)[collectionView      
  dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCustomCell1Identifier 
  forIndexPath:indexPath];
  //call cell1's specific properties if needed.
  cell = (BaseCollectionViewCell *) cell1;

  } else {

   ChildCell2 cell2 = (ChildCell2 *)[collectionView 
   dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCustomCell2Identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
  //call cell2's specific properties if needed.
  cell = (BaseCollectionViewCell *) cell2;

  }
//call common methods here.
```

Comment: Could you please also add that how the code will be in cellForItemAtIndexPath method like I have written in question?

Comment: BaseCollectionViewCell *cell; with it yes you can access common property in both cell , but what about others, ex childCell1 has one label named titleLabel , so cell.titleLabel is now not accessible because it is not part of ` BaseCollectionViewCell` hope you are getting my point

Comment: @MikeAlterwe can cast the cell to get cell's specific properties. I have added the comment.