# Accessing properties in a super class using super or this in the subclass?

Tags: java, inheritance

In terms of values for properties defined in the super class using the same property in the sub-class and the property is defined as protected, then using `super` or `this` does not make any difference right? **Then why does the language really have these ways of accessing the properties?** Is there a scenario where they will have different values?

```java
class A {
    protected int a = 15; 
}
        
class B extends A { 
    public void printA() {
        System.out.print(super.a) // prints 15
        System.out.print(this.a) // prints 15
    }
}
```

Comment: B extends A* - otherwise compilation error

Comment: Yes. Haven't typed all of it here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In *this* situation, it doesn't make any difference. However, as soon as you change to methods instead of variables, and introduce another method in `B` which shadows the one in `A`, *then* it makes a difference:

```
class A { 
    protected int a = 15; 
}

class B extends A { 
    private int a = 10;

    public void printA() {
       System.out.println(super.a); // prints 15
       System.out.println(this.a); // prints 10
    }
}
```

This is more common with methods than with fields though - often an overriding implementation needs to call the superclass implementation as part of its implementation:

```
public void foo() {
    super.foo();
    // Now do something else
}
```

I would personally recommend *avoiding* non-private fields, at which point the field part becomes irrelevant.

See [section 6.4.1 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1) for more on shadowing.

Comment: Ideed, member variables are not overridable. : [see this other thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/685300/233495)