# Java variable look up based on type not object

Tags: java, types, casting

I have the following code: http://ideone.com/Ww5bd8

```
class A {
     public int n = 1;
     public int get() { return n; }
}
 class B extends A {
     public int n = 2;
     public int get() { return n; }
}
class javaprog {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    B b = new B();
    A a = b;
    System.out.println("a = b");
    System.out.println(a.get());
    System.out.println(a.n);
    System.out.println(b.n);
  }
}
```

This results in the output:

```
a = b
2
1
2
```

No A is ever created so how is the 2nd line which assigns 1 to n ever executed. Surely a and b are the same instance because of object references, and so in memory how can a.n refer to a different location than b.n?

If n was static I could understand this but it is an instance variable.

Comment: `b` has two fields called `n`.

Comment: @assylias, I can't believe Java is such a popular language given that's true.

Comment: `"I can't believe Java is such a popular language given that's true."` -- wth?

Comment: this is certainly confusing and javac could give a warning.

Comment: Any decent IDE **will** give you a warning if you set it to do so, to warn you about variable shadowing -- which is exactly what you're doing here.

Comment: to be popular, it needs to be fast (enough). so it needs primitive constructs like fields access, which directly translates to memory access on fixed address,  therefore cannot use "dynamic dispatch" like instance methods.

Comment: Here's another similar question: [Java method overriding and variable shadowing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25847300/java-method-overriding-and-variable-shadowing)