# Why are protected instance members not visible inside a subclass within a different package, but protected class members are?

Tags: java

```
package one;

public class A {
    protected int first;
    protected static int second;
}
```

```
package two;

import one.A;

public class B extends A {
    public void someMethod() {
        this.first = 5; //works as expected
        B.second = 6; //works
        A a = new A();
        // a.first = 7; does not compile

        //works just fine, but why?
        a.second = 8; 
        A.second = 9;
    }
}
```

Why aren't the same restrictions applied to static fields, what's the idea behind it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [JLS 6.6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.2):

> *A protected member or constructor **of an object** may be accessed from outside the package* in which it is declared **only by code that is responsible for the implementation of that object.**

From [6.6.2.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.2.1):

> Let C be the class in which a protected member is declared. Access is permitted only within the body of a subclass S of C.

`this.first = 5;` works because `B` is an implementor of `A`.

`A.second` works because this restriction is only defined for members of an object. Same goes for `B.second`.

As for *why* it's specified this way, you'd have to ask the people defining the specification - we could only make assumpsions. **6.6.2.1 even has an example that expresses an issue similar to this**:

> Consider this example, where the points package declares:

```
package points;
public class Point {
    protected int x, y;
    void warp(threePoint.Point3d a) {
        if (a.z > 0)  // compile-time error: cannot access a.z
            a.delta(this);
    }
}
```

> and the threePoint package declares:

```
package threePoint;
import points.Point;
public class Point3d extends Point {
    protected int z;
    public void delta(Point p) {
        p.x += this.x;  // compile-time error: cannot access p.x
        p.y += this.y;  // compile-time error: cannot access p.y
    }
    public void delta3d(Point3d q) {
        q.x += this.x;
        q.y += this.y;
        q.z += this.z;
    }
}
```

> A compile-time error occurs in the method delta here: it cannot access the protected members x and y of its parameter p, because **while Point3d (the class in which the references to fields x and y occur) is a subclass of Point (the class in which x and y are declared), it is not involved in the implementation of a Point (the type of the parameter p)**. The method delta3d can access the protected members of its parameter q, because the class Point3d is a subclass of Point and is involved in the implementation of a Point3d.
>
> ---

I recommend checking out [Why we should not use `protected static` in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24289070/why-we-should-not-use-protected-static-in-java/24289761#24289761).

The semantics of `protected` were aimed at instance members - `protected static` is contradictive to the purpose of `protected`, which could be why it wasn't restricted in the same manner.

Comment: Hi,  I couldn't get the answer yet, how protected static variables can access ? In this scenario,  a.second = 8; is accessible

Comment: @nagendra547 The restriction was only set of instance members; class members aren't restricted in this manner. The specification only requires this for instance members.

Comment: well, you cannot  access class members e.g a.second,  if B is not extending A.

Comment: @nagendra547 That's covered by 6.6.2.1: "*Let C be the class in which a protected member is declared. Access is permitted only within the body of a subclass S of C.*" - Since `B` is a subclass of `A`, protected members can be accessed. 6.6.2 enforces the restriction of instance members. Two different contracts. `B` could still access `A.second` without the need to extend only if `B` were in the same package as `A`.

Comment: I have to say that this 'involved in the implementation of' business is pretty poor wording. 'Member of' would have been a lot better and a lot simpler.