# @RequestMapping can not use a static final constant in parent class which is not in same package with subclass

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

when @RequestMapping used a static final constan in parent class which is not in same package with subClass class,the idea give me a error like

> 'V1_BASE_URL' has protected access in 'XXXXXXXX.BaseController'

so,i dont know why,the next is my code.

this is the parent class

```
package com.controller;
public class BaseController {

protected static final String V1_BASE_URL = "/crm/v1/";
```

}

this is subclass,and it is not in the same package with `BaseController`

```
package com.controller.corpus;
@RequestMapping(V1_BASE_URL+"/crm/v1/corpus_subset")
public class CorpusSubsetController extends BaseController {

}
```

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zt37h.png)

i dont find some useful answer can deal my problem,but i found if the subclass and father in the same package,the annotation in classname can use `static constant`,but if the subclass not in the same package with father, the annotation can not use,so my question is the annotation in classname belongs who?if the annotation in a class which one in the package A,so the annotation belongs the package A??

Comment: This is a duplicate question and has been answered here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24289070/why-we-should-not-use-protected-static-in-java)

Comment: If it is not in the same package, you can't access protected attributes by design so this is expected.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between public, protected, package-private and private in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/what-is-the-difference-between-public-protected-package-private-and-private-in)

Comment: see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are trying to access `V1_BASE_URL` in the annotation which is outside the class scope. If you access it like this you won't have any compilation errors for example :

```
public class CorpusSubsetController extends BaseController {
    public void test() {
        String test = V1_BASE_URL;
    }
}
```

Comment: ok,thanks,but i also have question, when the subclass with father in the same package,the V1_BASE_URL can used in the annotation @RequestMapping,this annotation is outside the class scope too.