# Calling member with Sub class reference

Tags: java

I'm calling ChildTest class methods with ChildTest reference only i.e.

```
ChildTest child = new ChildTest(); // not dynamic dispatching.
```

My question is why child.foo() output is Test foo called 10

```
class Test {
    int x = 10;

    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("Test foo called " + x);

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ChildTest child = new ChildTest();

        System.out.println(child.x);
        child.foo();
        child.bar();
    }
}

class ChildTest extends Test {
    int x = 20;

    public void bar() {
        System.out.println("ChildTest Bar called " + x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well what is the problem...? You should explain you problem more comprehensively...

Comment: Add the relevant output here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables cannot be overridden in Java, so what you have done is that you have [*hidden*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html) the original `x` variable.

The fact that you have added a variable `x` in your `ChildTest` class and given it the value `20` does not affect the variable `x` from your `Test` class, which will still be `10`.

The method `foo()` still resides in the `Test` class, which means that it will use the `x` variable declared in that class. If you want to see a different output for a call from a `ChildTest` reference, you can add a `getX()` method and override it:

```
class Test {
    public int getX() {
        return 10;
    }
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("Test foo called " + getX());
    }
    ...

class ChildTest extends Test {
    @Override
    public int getX() {
        return 20;
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Variables are inherited the problem is that they cannot be overriden as you can do with methods.

Comment: I may be misinterpreting your first sentence, but it does not sound correct to me.

Comment: @Rafael: This was corrected an hour ago. Do you still have an issue with the answer?

Comment: @fd.: This was corrected an hour ago. Do you still have an issue with the answer?

Comment: @Keppil: That looks fine now.

Answer (score 0):

The line `int x = 20;` in ChildTest declares a *separate* variable also called `x`. An instance of ChildTest then has two unrelated variables named `x`, one from Test with value 10 and one from ChildTest with value 20. Code in class Test can only see the variable it declared itself, which is why it sees the value 10.

If you want ChildTest to modify the value rather than creating a separate variable, add a constructor (or initializer block) and set the variable there without redeclaring it:

```
class ChildTest extends Test {
    ChildTest() {
        x = 20;
    }

    public void bar() {
        System.out.println("ChildTest Bar called " + x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that there is no way to override variables in Java, what you are doing is hiding it.

Then, since main method is in the context of Test class the value of the variable is 10, in order to get 20 you shall be in the context of the `ChildTest` class or set the value of the `x` through a initialization block, constructor, or anything like this.

Here is more information:
 [Is there a way to override class variables in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685300/is-there-a-way-to-override-class-variables-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

`child` is the object refrence of `ChildTest`,when you call `foo()` method like `child.foo()`, it looks out for the method in `ChildTest` class,but there is no such method in it,however when it finds that it is inheriting a class that is `Test` class which is having this `foo()` method,Then it executes it and uses the instance variables of the `Test` class.