# method overriding Vs class variable overriding in java

Tags: java, methods, member, overriding

I was just trying some sample code for checking class variable overriding behavior in Java. Below is the code:

```
class A{
  int i=0;

  void sayHi(){
    System.out.println("Hi From A");
  }
}

 class B extends A{
  int i=2;

  void sayHi(){
    System.out.println("Hi From B");
  }
}


public class HelloWorld {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a= new B();
    System.out.println("i->"+a.i); // this prints 0, which is from A
    System.out.println("i->"+((B)a).i); // this prints 2, which is from B
    a.sayHi(); //  method from B gets called since object is of type B
  }
}
```

I am not able to understand whats happening at these two lines below

```
System.out.println("i->"+a.i); // this prints 0, which is from A
System.out.println("i->"+((B)a).i); // this prints 2, which is from B
```

Why does `a.i` print `0` even if the object is of type `B`? And why does it print `2` after casting it to `B`?

Comment: if you want to override class variable then look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/28263825/4726707

Comment: Thanks mate. I was aware of how to do it. But I was looking more into the root cause and why it happens. Got my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`i` is not a method - it's a data member. Data members don't override, they **hide**. So even though your instance is a `B`, it has two data members - `i` from `A` and `i` from `B`. When you reference it through an `A` reference you will get the former and when you use a `B` reference (e.g., by explicitly casting it), you'll get the latter.

Instance **methods**, on the other hand, behave differently. Regardless of the the type of the reference, since the instance is a `B` instance, you'll get the polymorphic behavior and get the string `"Hi From B"` printed.

Comment: Ok. So when we are using getters and setters, this issue won't come. Ideally we should not access class variables directly right?

Comment: @Amit.rk3 yes, indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Even though A is initialized as new B(), the variable is an A. if you say

```
B a = new B();
```

you won't have that problem.