# Binding in Java (overriding methods and "fields")

Tags: java, dynamic-binding, static-binding

```
public class Print1 {
    int x = 1;
    public void print(A a) { System.out.println(x); }
    public void print(B b) { System.out.println(x+1); }
}      

public class Print2 extends Print1 {
    int x = 3;
    public void print(A a) { System.out.println(x); }
    public void print(B b) { System.out.println(x+1); }
    public void print(C c) { System.out.println(x+2); }
}

// a tester class with main method 
A a = new A(); B b = new B(); C c = new C();
Print1 p1 = new Print1();
Print2 p2 = new Print2();
p1 = p2;

 System.out.println(p1.x); // Call 1, p1 is from Type Print1
 p1.print(c); /* Call 2
 //p1 is from Type Print2, print(B b) will be called */`
```

Class B is a subclass of Class A and C is a subclass of B.

1. why in Call 1 `P1` from type `Print1` even though it is referencing to Object of type `Print2` and in call 2 it is behaving as reference to `Print2`-object?
2. why in Call 2 `print(B b)` is called from `Print2` and not `print(C c)`?

This is the most confusing things for me so far in Java. Thank you for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30558552/method-overriding-vs-class-variable-overriding-in-java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30558552/method-overriding-vs-class-variable-overriding-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **type of the variable** is used to determine the class member that is accessed.

Therefore `p1.x` refers to the `x` field in `Print1`, not the one in `Print2`. (it would result in a compile time error, if you removed `x` from `Print1`.) The `x` field in `Print2` is a different field, i.e. `Print2` objects have 2 different `int` fields.

Also the `print(B b)` method is used in the expression `p1.print(c)` since `Print1` doesn't have a method `print(C c)`. (It would be a compile time error, if `C` wouldn't extend `B` or `A`.) Since `Print2` overrides the implementation of `Print1.print(B b)`, that implementation is used.

Answer (score 0):

First print works as expected due to **variable shadowing**.

You have a variable `p1` (type `Print1`) pointing to the object on the heap of the type `Print2`. Since `Print2` inherits from `Print1` this is allowed. And you are able to access the variable `x` of the `Print1` because there is no polymorphism for variables, they cannot "override" one another. Your variable type determined what `x` you wanted to fetch.

It would be less confusing if you would add another variable `int y` to `Print1` class. You could've accessed it as `System.out.println(p1.y);` without problems.

---

The second one also works as expected due to **polymorphism** (through inheritance).

Since `print(c)` method is executed on an object, the object is obviously of type `Print2` (does not matter what the variable type is (`Print1` or `Print2`), you will use the `Print2`'s method. Simply because the `Print2`'s method had overriden the `Print1`'s method.

Comment: Thank you darijan, that was helpful.