# How can I override @Autowired property in sub class

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns

I decide to override autowired field in sub class. How can I do this override? 
Something like this

```
class Superclass {
    @Autowired
    Test test;

    public Test getTest() {
        return test;
    }
}

class Subclass extends Superclass {
    @Autowired
    Test2 test2;

    public Subclass() {
        super().test=test2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to override class variables in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/685300/is-there-a-way-to-override-class-variables-in-java)

Comment: Definitely not a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks from @dok solution i override field  by this way:

```
class Superclass {
    private Test test;

    @Autowired
    public Test getTest(Test test) {
        return this.test = test;
    }
}

class Subclass extends Superclass {
    @Override
    @Autowired
    public Test getTest(Test2 test2) {
        return super.getTest(test2);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If understand correctly you want to have the value test2 auto filled and the method test() to use this new value.

There is no way in java to override a class variable, at least using a protected field will allow you to modify it's value in the subclass. 
But in this case i think it's better to override the getTest() method to return test2 instead.