# Accessing members of class after Upcasting in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, upcasting

I am going through my notes(after 5-6 months) and I am unable to understand the output given by following code :

```
class Base
{
    int x=20;
}

class Child extends Base 
{
    int x=50;

    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
       Base b = new Child();     //upcasting
       System.out.println(b.x);    // prints 20
    }
}
```

I expected the output to be `50` but the output is `20`. I don't understand ***reason*** behind this output.

I know `int x = 20` in `Base` is same as `Child` class's `int x = 50` resulting in data hiding . Also reference id of `Child` class is in `Base` class reference variable `b` resulting in upcasting .

Both of these should result in `50` as output , since `b` is having refernce id of the child class so `b.x` should be `50` and also because by data hiding `int x= 50` hides `int x = 20` .

So, why output is `50`.

Comment: Simple answer: Variables (fields) do not override.  Only methods override.

Comment: thanks for pointing that :)

Comment: refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/685300/is-there-a-way-to-override-class-variables-in-java