# inheritance of variable in groovy

Tags: grails, groovy

Maybe it is the late hours :) But can any one tell why parent class does pull variables from the child

```
Foo {
   public String myString = "My test string of Foo"

   public printOutString () {
       println this.myString
   }
}

Bar extends Foo {
   public String myString = "My test string of Bar"
}

Foo.printOutString() //prints out "My test string of Foo" as expected

Bar.printOutString() //prints out "My test string of Foo" as not expected thought it would take the String from Bar instead
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no field inheritance in Groovy [nor in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685300/is-there-a-way-to-override-class-variables-in-java). You can override the value of the field, as the linked question's answer suggest:

```
class Foo {
   public String myString = "My test string of Foo"

   public printOutString () {
       myString
   }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
   { myString = "My Bar" }
}


assert new Foo().printOutString() == "My test string of Foo"
assert new Bar().printOutString() == "My Bar"
```