# Array of type Grandparent can't access elements from Grandchild

Tags: java, arrays, parent-child, grandchild

I've created an array with a grandparent type, passed objects that are grandchildren of that type, but I can't access the elements from the child class. These aren't the exact things I'm coding they are just examples.

Here is the Grandparent

```
public class Animal {

String name = "Animal";


}
```

Here is the child class

```
public class Bird extends Animal {

String name = "Bird";

}
```

Here is the Grandchild class

```
public class RedBird extends Bird {
String name = "Red Bird";



}
```

The problem I am encountering is this

```
public class Room {
public static void main(String args[]) {

Animal[] anim = {new RedBird};

System.out.println(Animal[0].name);

 }
}
```

The program will output the wrong thing

```
Animal
```

Does anybody know how I can fix this? Thanks!

Comment: one way you can do is, you can create getName and override it in RedBird

Comment: elaborate. Just make a method with return name?

Comment: yeah in both classes

Comment: The fact that you declare the type `Animal` makes Java pick up the `name` associated with that class, the one that says "Animal".  That you declare the type `Animal[]` doesn't matter, it's still type `Animal`.  I don't know if that helps you to understand but it's part of the the Java typing system.  Using a method as TSM suggests helps because methods of the same name override, which gives different behavior and something more like what you probably want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java inheritance fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43579567/java-inheritance-fields)

Answer (score 2):

Another way to look at this is if you *don't* want this behavior, don't re-declare the field.  In other words, adding `String` declares a new field, and you don't want to do that.  You can use an initializer block or a constructor to assign a new name.

```
public class Animal {
  String name = "Animal";
}

public class Bird extends Animal {
  { name = "Bird"; }  // This is an initializer block
}

public class RedBird extends Bird {
  { name = "Red Bird"; }
}
```

This will print "Red Bird".

Comment: Which version of Java is this valid for? I've been out of the Java world for a long time and haven't seen this kind of reassignment of class fields before.

Comment: Syntax snafu on my part.  Fixed it with an initializer block.

Comment: This does not work for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You'll have to describe better what you are trying to do.  Your problem is obvious, you are using the wrong `name` field, but if this doesn't fix it, what do you want instead?  I think you want inheritance with method names, but that's obvious, so why are you not doing that?

Answer (score 2):

```
class Animal {
    String name;
    public Animal() {
        name = "Animal";
    }
}

class Bird extends Animal {
    public Bird() {
        name = "Bird";
    }
}

class RedBird extends Bird {
    public RedBird() {
        name = "RedBird";
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal a = new RedBird();
        System.out.println(a.name);
    }
}
```