# Variable hiding in java

Tags: java

Look at the code below :

```
class Rodent {

    protected int tailLength = 4;

    public void getRodentDetails() {
        System.out.println(this.tailLength);
    }
}

public class Mouse extends Rodent {
    protected  int tailLength = 8;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mouse mouse = new Mouse();
        mouse.getRodentDetails();
    }
}
```

Now `getRodentDetails()` is inherited.
When it is called by a `Mouse` reference , `this.tailLength` should print `8` and not `4` as parent `tailLength` is hidden in mouse.

Why does it print 4 ?

**EDIT :** The question is not about what is variable hiding and not also about how to try to override variables. The closest answer was given by JB Nizet in comments which I have expanded below as answer.

Comment: Because fields are not resolved polymorphically. Only instance methods are.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to override class variables in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685300/is-there-a-way-to-override-class-variables-in-java)

Comment: To make use of polymorphism, you can add a method `getTailLength()` to each of the classes that returns the class-specific `tailLength`.

Comment: If Mouse herite from Rodent, why declare tailLenght a second time ? ;)

Comment: wrong way of deduction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is because of [static binding](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/03/what-is-static-and-dynamic-binding-in.html).

> 1) Static binding in Java occurs during Compile time while Dynamic
>   binding occurs during Runtime.
>
> **2) private methods, final methods and static methods and variables uses static binding and bonded by compiler while virtual methods are
>   bonded during runtime based upon runtime object.**
>
> 3) Static binding uses Type(Class in Java) information for binding
>   while Dynamic binding uses Object to resolve binding.
>
> 4) Overloaded methods are bonded using static binding while overridden
>   methods are bonded using dynamic binding at runtime.

So,

```
protected int tailLength = 4;

public void getRodentDetails() {
    System.out.println(this.tailLength);
}
```

In this code , tailLength is associated to tailLength variable of Rodent class at compile time only.

Why did not `this` affected it ?
This is because `this` is resolved to memory address at Runtime.

Some people say it is due to variable hiding but variable hiding itself happens because of static binding.

Comment: *Some people say it is due to variable hiding but variable hiding itself happens because of static binding* --> So it's variable hiding!

Answer (score 2):

In Java you can [overwrite](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) methods, not properties. But you can hide them instead.

So whenever you are calling `tailLength` property inside of `Mouse` class, you are hidding `tailLength` property from `Rodent` class, and using the value from `Mouse` class.

If you want to overwrite this value, you should use this construction:

```
class Rodent {
    // we add final to make sure value is always set
    protected final int tailLength;

    // default constructor
    protected Rodent() { this(4); }
    // use to overwrite tailLength  value
    protected Rodent(int tailLength ) { this.tailLength =tailLength; }

    public void getRodentDetails() {
        System.out.println(this.tailLength);
    }
}
```

And the Mouse class:

```
public class Mouse extends Rodent {
    public Mouse (){
      super(8);
    }
    ...
}
```

That way you will be able to set tails length without any overwrites, but simply using OOP.

Answer (score 0):

variables are not overridden like functions you should initialize them in constructor

```
    public Mouse (){
     super.tailLength = 8;
    }
```

by defining it will make other variable that is unknown to mouse class